# beanutils set property of hashmap

Tags: java, hashmap, key, apache-commons-beanutils

My objects

```
public class Scheme {
    private SchemeDetails details;

    // Getter and seteers
}

public class SchemeDetails {
    private HashMap<String, String> detailsMaster;

    public HashMap<String, String> getDetailsMaster() {
        return detailsMaster;
    }

    public void setDetailsMaster(HashMap<String, String> detailsMaster) {
        this.detailsMaster = detailsMaster;
    }
}
```

I need to append one value to detailsmaster with already existing value. So I tried below

```
BeanUtils.setProperty(scheme, "details.detailsMaster[key]", "1234");
```

but it is not working. I checked in java doc of beanutils. It says in property argument we can use like *nested/indexed/mapped/combo*. But there is no example given. Please help me with this.

Comment: first param of setProperty() method should be an instance of Scheme.

Comment: yes it is instance of scheme. I changed in post as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax should be

```
BeanUtils.setProperty(scheme, "details.detailsMaster(key)", "1234");
```